# Using python in windows to run a remote perl script on linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, perl, ssh

I need to connect from a Windows machine to a remote Linux server and execute a Perl script.
I've tried using

```
command = "perl /usr/local/xfer/file.pl -ssh root@"+hostname+" -pw password -batch"
pid = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
```

but it tells me `Can't open perl script "usr/local/xfer/file.pl'": No such file or directory.`

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command above uses the Perl installation on Windows but you said the script is located on a Linux server.

So you need to wrap the invocation in a call to ssh:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(['plink', '-ssh', 'user@server', 'perl', '/usr/local/xfer/file.pl', 
            '-ssh', 'root@'+hostname, '-pw', 'password', '-batch'], shell=True)
```

Note: **Never** ever use the "string command" version of `subprocess.Popen()`, always pass command and arguments as a **list**.

Back to your problem: This will start `plink` (command line version of Putty since Windows doesn't have `ssh(1)`) with all the other list elements as arguments.

Note that the Putty Agent must run for this to work, otherwise `plink` will ask for a password. See the manual for details.

Comment: This helped a lot.  After I put plink.exe into my python path, all I really needed for it to work was `subprocess.call(['plink', '-ssh', '%s@%s' %(USER,HOST), '-pw', PASSWORD, 'perl', '//usr/local/xfer/file.pl'], shell=True)`